# how to Remove text onfocus of EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a scenario, for example, a EditText in acitivity  instead of using Textview as a label of it i want to put text "UserName" inside EditText and if user clicks on it.
it should disappear and EditText should get empty to enter data in it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

android:hint="username"

put this attribute in EditText

thats it.

Answer (score 1):

onclickListener does not work with EditText items, you'll have to use an OnFocusListener.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setOnClickListener()` to register a listener that then checks if the EditText just contains "UserName", and clears it out if that is true.